# Nagios core monitoring is occasionally not working for directories owned by newly added users in RHEL6.9

Tags: nagios

In my environment, we have a Nagios server monitoring the incoming files in directories owned by different users, we have some checks already configured and working fine, but it is causing a problem with newly added services while everything is the same, also we can observe that monitoring sometimes continues and other time it stops with error no such file or directory in Nagios web interface. 
There is no error in logs also as per my best belief configuration is fine, so if anyone can help, will be great.

Comment: You should include your script code for that check.

Comment: Actually script is big and there is no option to attach it, it's working fine for more than 14 directories monitoring but for every newly added directory monitoring, nagios fails, i want to know if there is limitation regarding the number of services that can only be monitored.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your script and add some debug messages to new logfile.